# Probability distribution of a probability distribution

Tags: probability

I am looking at a problem in which I have found a probability distribution, but this formula involves another random variable with its own probability distribution. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the concept, and am also wondering if there is a way I can eliminate this variable. Especially since the pdf of the variable includes the variable itself and so I cannot find some expression without it.

Is this a known concept and can I find similar problems or more reading on it?

Comment: Can you show us the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a conditional probability such as $P[X=5|Y]$.  Or you are incorrectly working with two random variables.  For example the following manipulation for two random variables is incorrect: $$P[X+Y\leq 5] = P[X\leq 5-Y] = F_X(5-Y)$$